# HTTP 1.1 20 second delay compared to HTTP 1.0

Tags: c, windows, http, post

I've written a program in C that sends a `HTTP 1.1 POST` request to a web server.
Well monitoring it with wireshark, takes less then a second for the server to respond and to get the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` message, but then it takes another 20 seconds to get the `FIN, ACK` packet, which I believe this is what causes `recv` to return 0, specifying no more data.
Causing my program to hang for 20ish seconds well it waits for the server to send the `FIN, ACK` packet.

I've tested this with `HTTP 1.0`, and there isn't a delay. So I think this is because `HTTP 1.1` by default considers all connections as `persistent connections`.
But my web browser uses `HTTP 1.1` and there's no delay, so I think i'm not doing something right.

One idea I had was instead of waiting for `recv` to return 0, I should check if i'm at the end of the document some other way, but I can't think of any way to do this.

So if anyone could explain to me how I should be doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we would need to see some code ...  How are you opening and servicing the socket?  andy sock options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 defaults to keep-alive connections while 1.0 does not.  You can request a non-keep-alive by adding in the header

```
Connection: close
```

which instructs the server to close the connection as soon as it's complete.

Comment: This fixes the delay, but what if I want to take advantage of the keep-alive connections. How would I know if i've received all the data I'm supposed to before I stop calling `recv`?

Comment: You will now either due to the Content-Length header or by decoding the chunked encoding information.

Comment: In short, properly handling HTTP 1.1 is a lot more complicated.